# Unable to post query string via CURL

Tags: php, curl

URL Working fine in Browser after accepting the exception , but not working in curl.

My code is as follows :::

PHP CODE :

```
     <?php


        $str1 = "https://50.60.70.80/servlet/API";

        $url = $str1."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        echo $url;


        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);


        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        echo curl_errno($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
          echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        else {
                echo 'Success: '.$data;
        }

        curl_close($ch);


        ?>





    URL : https://50.60.70.80/servlet/API?userName=Test&password=pwd&message=My_Message&mobile=5555558888

Error getting while using through command line with "-k" and "-v":

 ***** About to connect() to 50.60.70.80 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 50.60.70.80... connected
* Connected to 50.60.70.80 (50.60.70.80) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_DHM_RSA_W1TH_AES_128_CBC_SEA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: E=abcd@mnmn.com,OU=lelna,O=teledna
*       start date: Mar 01 09:51:25 2013 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 01 09:51:25 2014 GMT
*       common name: (nil)
*       issuer: E=abcd@mnmn.com,OU=lelna,O=teledna
> GET /servlet/API?UserName=Test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.3.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: 50.60.70.80
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2013 16:38:57 GMT
<
status=FAILED,transid=4526698561,reasoncode=201
* Connection #0 to host 50.60.70.80 left intact
* Closing connection #0****
```

### Can anybody help ?

I am using following versions ::
PHP Version -- 5.3.3
CURL Version -- 7.19.7
Using Apache

Comment: not working how? returns bad data? crashes?

Comment: returns no data.. Actually calling the php file from my Application server/Application Browser .. If from browser browser times out. If from application not getting success code.

tried doing the same from command line window by writing 

curl -k -v --url >> and then the url..

The error which i got is shown in the above snippet.

Comment: Should you be URL encoding your URL? Perhaps that may help, in case of dodgy characters being passed?

Comment: tried by passing 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,urlencode($url));

Getting error could not resolve hostname

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this

**EDITED :**

```
curl_setopt( $ch ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
```

Comment: Tried with all these :

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,urlencode($str1));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

Comment: @KmrGtm, why are you using HTTGET,1 and POST,1 in the same code ? How would that be supposed to work ?

Comment: @ Shankar 

I tried them in different scripts one by one .. getiing same result..

tried by passing curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,urlencode($url)); Getting error could not resolve hostname –

Comment: @KmrGtm, Nope don't do `urlencode`. Seems like you are sending data via GET, so try my edited answer above. More importantly, don't remove the RETURNTRANSFER parameter , it is required.

Comment: Thanks @ Sankar .. 

Actually i figured out some more errors .Original  PHP Code , which i tried earlier is also correct and working fine .. 

But the Real prob is :

My php file is in Webserver. If iam calling the php file from the webserver itself using this command " php url.php " , its running fine . But in the real scenario , i want to call the php file from a Application server . That is what is creating problem. Any recommendation ?